# Books for Practice Problems

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

I'm not asking for the solution to the question posted below, but instead for references to books where I can find similar questions. [image]

I'd be grateful for any advice you can give. Thank you.

Comment: @jared do you have any idea?

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Problem-Solvers-Solution/dp/0878915338/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1364332365&sr=8-1&keywords=rea+advanced+calculus) seems like a decent book for what you're looking for, but I'll admit I've not used it. I only looked at the Table of Contents.

Comment: Also Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis is full of excercises